# WinForms dev express bind true/false column with a checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm working on a **Windows Forms** project and I have some data in a `XtraGrid.GridControl` with these columns:

`ID`, `Description`, `To Process`

I'm loading these data from database, and the column `To Process` contains a `boolean` field.

I would like to have instead of the current `1` and `0` values a checkbox, that will be checked if the value is `1` and unchecked if the value is `0`.

How can I achieve this with `Dev Express 16`?

---

This is what I did so far:

- imported a `DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl` in my form `Design`;
- added three columns `ID`, `Description` and `To Process`;
- populated the `GridControl` `DataSource` from *code behind* with this method:

  ```
  private void LoadTableData()
  {
    // initialization
    gcTable.DataSource = null;

    string query = " SELECT id, description, to_process FROM test_table ";
    DataTable dt = Utils.ExecuteQuery(query);

    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
      gcTable.DataSource = dt;
    }
  }
  ```

As now, I have my table populated but with `1` and `0` values in the column `To Process`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a [RepositoryItemCheckEdit](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit) to your `To Process` column's [ColumnEdit](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.ColumnEdit) property and set its **ValueChecked** and **ValueUnchecked** properties if necessary. More information [here](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/753/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/data-editing-and-validation/modify-and-validate-cell-values).

Comment: How to allow multiple selection? Thanks!

Comment: I got it. I changed `ValueChecked` and `ValueUnchecked` from `true` and `false` to `1` and `0`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit` event to change repository for a cell of grid view. If data column is type of bool, cells of grid control will be check boxes.

```
dt.Columns["to_process"].DataType = typeof(bool);
```

Here is a sample code for CustomRowCellEdit event.

```
    void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName == "to_process")
        {
            DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit repChk = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit();
            e.RepositoryItem = repChk;
        }
    }
```